# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions' not found

Tags: php, laravel, http, laravel-5, guzzle

I have a simple registration form I would like to send post data to external service using guzzle

Here is what I have so far in the register controller

```
 protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            ]);

        $client = new Client();
        $response = $client->post('app.salesmanago.pl/api/contact/insert', [
            GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON => [        
            'allow_redirects' => true,
            'timeout' => 2000,
            'http_errors' => true,
            'headers' => [
                'Accept' => 'application/json, application/json',
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'clientId' => 'mykey',
                'apiKey' => 'mykey',

            ],
            'form_params' => [
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'email' => $data['email'],
            ]

          ]
        ]);


    dd($response);

        return $user;
    }
```

Now when I fill the form and send the form data I get the following error

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions' not found
```

Note I have installed guzzle like this:  `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:~6.0`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Add a slash before `GuzzleHttp`, so it looks like `\GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions`

Comment: @aynber that solved my problem now no name or email displayed just this https://ibb.co/ZLvhxjN  why?

Comment: It will only show what the other server sends back, not what you're sending. Try `dd($response->getBody());` to see if there's a body to the response.

Comment: @aynber now I tried `    $response =$request->getBody();
    dd($response);` i get this https://ibb.co/k675Wr5 is this okay?